# Dissociation of 4-aminobenzoic acid in aqueous solution

Tags: acid-base, aromatic-compounds, amino-acids

I believe that 4-aminobenzoic acid's structural formula is 
$\ce{C7H7NO2}$

Hence, $$\ce{C7H7NO2 + H2O -> ?}$$

what are the dissociation products of the 4-aminobenzoic acid in aqueous solution ?

Comment: Try to draw a structure of 4-aminobenzoic acid.

Comment: You can't possibly deduce the reaction from the *molecular formula*.

Answer (score 0):

4-aminobenzoic acid can be represented by the formula $\ce{H2N(C6H4)COOH}$, where the $\ce{C6H4}$ is the benzene ring minus two hydrogen atoms.

The group $\ce{RNH2}$ is basic, meaning the following happen:

$$\ce{RNH2 + H2O <<=> RNH3+ + OH-}$$

The group $\ce{R'COOH}$ is acidic, meaning the following happen:

$$\ce{R'COOH + H2O <<=> RCOO- + H3O+}$$

Combined:

$$\ce{H2N(C6H4)COOH + H2O <<=> ^+H3N(C6H4)COO- + H2O}$$

Comment: So, what is the water doing there?

Comment: @orthocresol catalyst of proton transfer?